# Managing and sorting home movies and shorts in iTunes?

Tags: video, itunes

I currently have a large collection of short movies from Youtube and quite a large selection of home movies.

What is the best way of managing all these files? I need to keep them separated from my iTunes purchases and DVD rips...

I'd like to sort them in separate pools (movies, shorts, home movies) but also categorize them even the home movies (vacations, weddings, paintball events...).

I would like to access them from the Apple TV, sync to iPhone etc... So I'm stuck with iTunes.

How should I proceed to organize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty personal question, but:

Personally, I keep home movies in iPhoto. Seems a better location to me. They go with the photos of the event, keeps everything together. iPhoto for me is personal collections of events, and iTunes is proper content to watch.

Shorts go in Movies (you can't create a top-level category in iTunes) with everything else. You can use Playlists to categorize. You can set your own Genre in the meta-data to aid categorization.

Comment: Using iTunes for home movies sounds like a sensible advice. but for the short movies I want to be able to categorize them as well. I want mainly to be able to look through all my movies but without the shorts bloating my movies list. I think there must be some sort of creative solution there.

Comment: I think I would put it into Browse by Genre mode, and tag the shorts in one genre, and normal in another. That'll give you your two buckets.